# How to choose a setting from a set, when the act of choosing automatically sets the value?

Tags: interaction-design

Here's the scenario: The user is on a screen where they are able to change several settings. Any changes in the UI are immediately committed (there's no edit/save interaction).

The question: One of these settings is to choose a logging level from a set of options. What's the best way to represent to the user these options? We currently have a drop-down, but the interaction doesn't make it clear that something is changing in the back end.

Also of note: This is not a web site. This is for enterprise software.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot/mockup?

Comment: I don't understand why "the interaction doesn't make it clear that something is changing in the back end." It acts like all other options in the screen, doesn't it?

Comment: @dnbrv Yeah, perhaps you're right. Maybe I'm just not used to this paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, you're doing the right thing by avoiding drop down, because some browser fires an "onChange()" event when you hit arrow up/down key, while other browser requires you to hit enter key to fire the "onchange()" event.  This is particularly important to note when your screen lacks Save button.

So I guess your only other logical choices would be radio buttons or pills.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9hOay.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

An alternative would be to use radio Button Groups in Bootstrap framework.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons